# Create a Program Displaying Number of Numbers Greater Than 0.8 in Matrix

Tags: for-loop, matrix, octave

New programmer here,

I got a task to make a program that picks and displays how many numbers greater than 0.8 there is in a random matrix 5x6 with 2 for loops and would appreciate help if someone knows how to make it.

Thanks in advance.

I'm writing in Octave,

this is how the code starts:

```
clear

clc

rand(5,6);

for row =….
```

Comment: Why do you need two loops? `nnz( rand(5,6) > 0.8 )` would give you this result... Please write a [mcve] detailing your specific problem, like do you not understand [loops](https://octave.org/doc/v4.2.1/The-for-Statement.html), or [variables](https://octave.org/doc/v4.2.2/Assignment-Ops.html), or [indexing](https://octave.org/doc/v4.2.1/Index-Expressions.html), or [comparisons](https://octave.org/doc/v4.0.1/Comparison-Ops.html), or...?

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully, this MATLAB code carries over to Octave. The first method uses two for-loops to scan/traverse through the matrix. If the value retrieved from the matrix during scanning `Matrix(Row,Column)` is greater than 0.8 then the variable `Number` is incremented. This process repeats until the whole matrix is checked. `Numbers_Greater_Than` is used to store all the numbers that are greater than 0.8.

### Using For-Loops:

```
clear;
clc;
Matrix = rand(5,6);
Numbers_Greater_Than = [];
[Number_Of_Rows,Number_Of_Columns] = size(Matrix);


Number = 0;
for Row = 1: Number_Of_Rows
    for Column = 1: Number_Of_Columns

    if(Matrix(Row,Column) > 0.8)
        Number = Number + 1;
        Numbers_Greater_Than = [Numbers_Greater_Than Matrix(Row,Column)];
    end
    end
end

fprintf("The are %d numbers greater than 0.8 in the matrix\n",Number);
Numbers_Greater_Than
```

## Extension:

**Alternatively:**
Scanning through the elements using single number indexing.

```
clear;
clc;
Matrix = rand(5,6);

Number = 0;
for Element = 1: numel(Matrix)   

    if(Matrix(Element) > 0.8)
        Number = Number + 1;
    end
     
end

fprintf("The are %d numbers greater than 0.8 in the matrix\n",Number);
```

### Using a Logical Array:

This method creates a logical array based on the condition `> 0.8`. The `Logical_Array` is set to "1" when the condition is true and set to "0" when the condition is false. By taking the sum afterwards the number of times that the condition is true in the matrix can be counted.

```
clear;
clc;
Matrix = rand(5,6);

Logical_Array = Matrix > 0.8;
Number = sum(Logical_Array,'all');
fprintf("The are %d numbers greater than 0.8 in the matrix\n",Number);
```

**Ran using MATLAB R2019b**

Comment: adding that the first two versions work fine in Octave (v 5.2.0).  The third does not because octave has not yet implemented the new flag 'all' for sum. See https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?58116.    so for a 2d array this would work in Octave by replacing that line with:  `Number = sum(sum(Logical_Array));`

Comment: Octave compatibility note: double-quoted string literals have different semantics in Matlab and Octave. In this particular case, it'll work okay, but in general, you need to avoid them if you want portable code.